# Cannot Edit the Length of VSE's Transform Efffect

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am new to Blender: So I have a video clip in Blender's VSE. I would like it to zoom into a specific part of the video for about 100 frames. I found that you can zoom by adding a transform effect strip to the video. However, I can't change the length of the effect (it spans the entire video and the "length" parameter in the side menu is greyed out) What can I do? Thanks!

[AV]

Answer (score 1):

Try cutting the strip at the places you want the zoom to occur. Then add the Transform effect to only this short strip. You can add keyframes by hovering over the scale value and pressing the i-key. Use the F-curve editor to change the keyframes in time.

Answer (score 0):

Effect strips get its length from source strip. So you can do following:

1. Resize or trim source strip
2. Animate **scale** property of transform strip.